# I am an international PhD student and I want to do a visiting research VISA, Which type of visa should I do ? ( I want finance myself )

Tags: phd, thesis, united-kingdom, visa, visiting

I am a Tunisian PhD student, at my last year of PhD, I found a lab from UK and I want to do a visiting research PhD with them (during 7 months), PS: I will finance myself. I don't have a big background about the visa. Thus, I have a question Which type of visa I should applied for ?

Comment: The UK university is likely to have an "Office for International Scholars", or something similar, and you should pose your question to them. (Assuming that someone from the lab has agreed to host you.)

Comment: @Noober Before you apply for a visa, you definitely ought to consult with someone who knows this stuff and can tell you what your chances are. Not that I know anything about obtaining a UK visa, but I strongly suspect that "I will finance myself" may be a major red flag for UK Visas and Immigration that will place a significant burden proof on you. If your visa is refused, this may make it substantially more difficult for you to obtain a UK visa in the future. Travel.stackexchange is probably a better place for such questions.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are registered for your PhD program abroad, you likely can likely visit UK research institutions on a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-as-an-academic). You may need to complete [ATAS](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/find-out-if-you-require-an-atas-certificate) before applying for a visa. Depending on your exact situation, a work visa may be more appropriate.

Applying for a UK visa is an expensive and long process. It may be wise to ask your host organisation for help before you apply.

Comment: My understanding is that being registeed for the PhD programme is unsufficient. The visit needs to be an integral part of the visitor's PhD studies at their home institution.

Comment: The page linked also says that for visits over 6 months you would normally need a PhD already, so if OP wants to visit for 7 months as a PhD student that might not work. I agree with the answer though that it would be best to work with the host organisation.

Comment: I think this would fall under the [study purpose](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-to-study) of the visitor rules rather than the academic one. "You can visit the UK for up to 6 months to: ...do a short piece of research that’s relevant to your course overseas". And as Pieter points out, 6 months is going to be the limit for someone at PhD student level.